# pip list shows different pip version than pip --version

Tags: python, pip

I am using pyenv on Mac M1 and face some issues:

if I run   `python -m pip -V` I get

```
pip 23.1 from /Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

but if I run `python -m pip show pip`
I get

```
Name: pip
Version: 23.0.1
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

I assume my `pip.conf` file might hold a wrong path? but I cannot find it with pyenv (as it is not in home folder)

---

I checked `/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages` as per the kind comment and first checked the /pip/ folder in there:

it holds a `__init__.py` file stating:

```
from typing import List, Optional

__version__ = "23.1"


def main(args: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> int:
    """This is an internal API only meant for use by pip's own console scripts.

    For additional details, see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7498.
    """
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper

    return _wrapper(args)
```

it also has the following folders:

```
pip-22.3.1.dist-info
pip-23.0.1.dist-info
pip-23.0.dist-info
pip-23.1.dist-info
```

`ls /Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages | grep pip`
showed:

```
pip
pip-22.3.1.dist-info
pip-23.0.1.dist-info
pip-23.0.dist-info
pip-23.1.dist-info
```

Comment: One explanation that I can think of is that you might have some incorrect metadata in the installation site  (maybe some leftovers from installation or upgrades that went wrong). If I were you I would list the content of the `/Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages` directory and check for anything related to `pip`. If possible add this content to your question so that we can guide you: `ls /Users/mypc/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages | grep pip`.

Comment: OK. Just as I thought you have leftover metadata from previous installations of *pip*. You should only ever have one and only one `.dist-info` directory per library/tool. Since the `pip/__init__.py` file contains the line `__version__ = "23.1"`, I recommend you delete all `pip-*.dist-info` directories except `pip-23.1.dist-info`. Then it should be all good. You could run `pyhton -m pip install --upgrade pip` afterwards for good measure and check that you still have one and only one `pip-*.dist-info` directory.

Comment: The next question is... How did this happen? And then hope that it does not happen again. By the way you might also want to check that it did not happen for other installations besides *pip*. You should have only one `.dist-info` directory per installed tool/library.

Comment: oh my i seem to have a lot of multiple .dist-info :( I am not sure how it happened. I usually install through pip with terminal in vscode